# How to get element of a list in python

Tags: python

I have the following the function:

```
price = client.futures_recent_trades(symbol="BTCUSDT", limit=1)
```

of type `<class 'list'>`
that has output:

```
[{'id': 1644406868, 'price': '58024.69', 'qty': '0.009', 'quoteQty': '522.22', 'time': 1637262411652, 'isBuyerMaker': False}]
```

and:

I want to return **price** value only : `'price': '58024.69'` and therefore,

`print(len(price))=1` but `print(len(price[0]))= 6`

But when I tried `price[0][1]`, it throws an error `list index out of range`

Comment: `price[0].price` since `price` is a list of dictionaries/objects, price should be renamed to something like `trades` then it would be `trades[0].price` which would make more sense

Comment: price[0]["price"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a dictionary within a list, so you should pass the key for the second index, like shown below.

```
price[0]['price']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> list(price[0].items())[1]
('price', '58024.69')
```

Answer (score 0):

thisdict = dict(price)

x = thisdict.get("price")

print("price: " + x)